# Windows 10 22H2 seems extremely slow when starting since cumulative October 2023 update. How can I fix that?

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

I still have a PC with four spinning hard disks (mainly because flash was really expensive for that capacity when I configured that PC), but performance using Windows was acceptable.

Only exceptions were updates that took "forever" (i.e. over one hour for the monthly updates) (I only have a Linux (openSUSE Leap) installation on that PC where installing updates is like 100 times faster).

Anyway since having installed the cumulative October 2023 update booting Windows is terribly slow (like 4 minutes until I can type the password, and another 3 minutes until the user's environment has been set-up).
Inspecting the event log I cannot find anything special, except that some services report they are slow starting.

What could be the reason, and is there a way to fix that?

#### Some System Details

I have no extra virus protection software installed (i.e.: using Windows Defender), but I have installed "Acronis True Image 2021" (with the "Active Protection" being disabled).
Also when booting I typically do not have a network connection (that would be via USB-WLAN).

The disks are using [Intel Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Rapid_Storage_Technology) in RAID-1 configuration, so I guess random reads should be even faster than for a single disk (until the IRST driver does something really stupid).
Motherboard is an Asus Z87-C.

#### Performance Diagnostics

```xml
Protokollname: Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational
Quelle:        Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance
Datum:         16.12.2023 00:08:16
Ereignis-ID:   100
Aufgabenkategorie:Systemstart-Leistungsüberwachung
Ebene:         Kritisch
Schlüsselwörter:Ereignisprotokoll
Benutzer:      Lokaler Dienst
Computer:      I74X4W7
Beschreibung:
Windows wurde gestartet: 
    Startdauer      :       :   315950ms
    Beeinträchtigung        :   false
    Vorfallzeit (UTC)   :   ‎2023‎-‎12‎-‎15T23:01:11.782601300Z
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance" Guid="{cfc18ec0-96b1-4eba-961b-622caee05b0a}" />
    <EventID>100</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>4002</Task>
    <Opcode>34</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000010000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-12-15T23:08:16.0527129Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1604</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{98f27fdd-2faa-0004-ae83-f298aa2fda01}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="5220" ThreadID="6504" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>I74X4W7</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BootTsVersion">2</Data>
    <Data Name="BootStartTime">2023-12-15T23:01:11.7826013Z</Data>
    <Data Name="BootEndTime">2023-12-15T23:06:54.8208231Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemBootInstance">549</Data>
    <Data Name="UserBootInstance">518</Data>
    <Data Name="BootTime">315950</Data>
    <Data Name="MainPathBootTime">261738</Data>
    <Data Name="BootKernelInitTime">41</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDriverInitTime">3222</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDevicesInitTime">18833</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPrefetchInitTime">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPrefetchBytes">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootAutoChkTime">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootSmssInitTime">27644</Data>
    <Data Name="BootCriticalServicesInitTime">80868</Data>
    <Data Name="BootUserProfileProcessingTime">172892</Data>
    <Data Name="BootMachineProfileProcessingTime">89</Data>
    <Data Name="BootExplorerInitTime">41702</Data>
    <Data Name="BootNumStartupApps">30</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPostBootTime">54212</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsRebootAfterInstall">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseStepImprovementBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseGradualImprovementBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseStepDegradationBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseGradualDegradationBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsDegradation">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsStepDegradation">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsGradualDegradation">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootImprovementDelta">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDegradationDelta">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsRootCauseIdentified">false</Data>
    <Data Name="OSLoaderDuration">4621</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPNPInitStartTimeMS">41</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPNPInitDuration">10112</Data>
    <Data Name="OtherKernelInitDuration">4329</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemPNPInitStartTimeMS">14300</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemPNPInitDuration">255</Data>
    <Data Name="SessionInitStartTimeMS">14698</Data>
    <Data Name="Session0InitDuration">2311</Data>
    <Data Name="Session1InitDuration">264</Data>
    <Data Name="SessionInitOtherDuration">25068</Data>
    <Data Name="WinLogonStartTimeMS">42343</Data>
    <Data Name="OtherLogonInitActivityDuration">4710</Data>
    <Data Name="UserLogonWaitDuration">27088</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: I have a 10 year Lenovo system with Windows 10 and a 7200-rpm Hitachi drive. It starts fully in about 4-5 minutes including logon. A regular update (download, install and restart) is 8-10 minutes total including logon.  Give some consideration to fully backing up and reinstalling Windows 10. Some software or OS corruption could be causing your slownes..

Comment: These kind of issues are now obselete with the prices and types of SSD's available on the market. buy the capacity SSD you need, then copy your current HDD image over to the new SSD.

If you really want to find out whats going on, try using perfmon. This will also probably say that the I/O transfer rate of the mechanical drives is at 100% MOTT (most of the time)

Comment: Perhaps before spending money on a older machine and an end of life OS, consider putting the money to a newer faster computer with modern hardware and Windows 11

Comment: Honestly it’s probably the drive or the amount of software you have configured to automatically start. Acronis is an absolutely performance killer, sadly

Comment: I would suggest to verify the health of the disk by examining its SMART attributes, especially if the disk is not new. Drastic slowdowns may mean the degradation of the disk. If you don't have software for that, try CrystalDiskInfo or Speccy. Add the screenshot of these attributes to your post for examination.

Comment: As others mentioned, Windows 10 EOL is less than a year away.Even if it can be made faster, support ends. Consider testing another OS. You can run Linux from USB without installation, and possibly Windows 11 using WinToUSB (https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html) or something similar , **if** the hardwaer is Win 11 compatible.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I see that the disk is actually at "100%" a lot of time, but still that can mean two things: 1) The disks are really slow, or 2) Windows is flooding the disk with many (useless?) I/O requests. Also: The performance was not that bad before the October update.

Comment: @John I can imaging that Microsoft deliberately made Windows 10 slow, just to make Windows 11 virtually faster (Maybe you remember Microsoft did something similar for "DR DOS" to make it look slower than "MS DOS").

Comment: @DrMoishePippik First the hardware isn't compatible for Windows 11 (6th generation Intel Core CPU), second I don't want a software company to tell me when I should replace my hardware. 4 cores /8 threads at 4GHz should be still fast enough.

Comment: Microsoft did NOT make Windows 10 deliberately slow. Once going the machine above is fast.  One physical Windows 10 machine I had with an SSD was very fast.

Comment: @harrymc I regularly monitor the S.M.A.R.T attributes, and the disks are fine.

Comment: As you say that there's no immediate internet on boot, freezes can be caused by unsuccessful internet access. Try booting with immediate internet access such as by using ethernet, to see if that's the problem. In that case, you might need to find the guilty system service and set its Startup to Delayed for internet to be available.

Comment: @harrymc As I don't see my Windows PC being a cloud client, why should it be terribly slow when there's no Internet during boot? Once again it seems Microsoft tries to re-educate us to believe you cannot use a computer without Internet access. Anyway I see a name resolution issue for "wpad", "201.30.42.23.in-addr.arpa" and "_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.NT-AUTORITÄT" (among others). I thought Windows were clever enough to realize that there is no Internet connection.

Comment: @U.Windl, as you say, you *don't* need MS to dictate your hardware or your OS choices. There *are* other operating systems. This comment is being written on a dual-boot Win10/Ubuntu PC. Ubuntu for speed, Win10 for a few specific apps that do not run in Ubuntu under wine, or have native Linux versions.

Comment: @U.Windl: Our site exists because Windows or any OS are not "intelligent". I suggest doing my test of connecting via ethernet. "WPAD" might mean Web Proxy Auto-Discovery.